# Angularjs ng-click doesn't fire inside directive

Tags: angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-click

I created a directive that adds a line of table when one clicks on the button to add to the level of the directive -- more precisely the button of the last column. I want that when one clicks on this button that a method is in my controller and then call

```
    myapp.directive("newCandidat", function() {
        return {
            restrict : "E",
            template : "<tr>"+
                          "<td><input  class='form-control' value='' disabled='disabled'></td>"+
                          "<td><input  class='form-control' value='' disabled='disabled'></td>"+
                          "<td><input  class='form-control' value=''></td>"+
                          "<td><button ng-click='method()'>click</button></td>"+
                        "</tr>",
            replace: true,
            transclude:true,
            terminal: true,
            scope:{method:'&'},
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(element);
              }

        };
    });

    myapp.controller("Controller",function($scope,$compile){
        $scope.addCand=function(){
            angular.element($("#candList")).append($compile("<new-candidat method='clickMe()'><new-candidat>")($scope));
        }
        $scope.clickMe=function(){
           console.log("Click me"); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bit surprising, but it works without `terminal: true`. It seems that `terminal:true` stops compiling a directive's template, even if it's the only directive applied to an element. Check out this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SVQNPLqbW2B7z29vJ8yf?p=preview) to see it working.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> terminal
>
> If set to true then the current priority will be the last set of
>   directives which will execute (any directives at the current priority
>   will still execute as the order of execution on same priority is
>   undefined). Note that expressions and other directives used in the
>   directive's template will also be excluded from execution.

This was also reported [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9250).

Do you need `terminal: true`? If so, your directive may have to compile its contents. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31368227/6382928).

Comment: can you tell me in witch situation we use terminal?

Comment: There may be situations where you need to control the timing of what gets compiled. Check out these links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969610/why-use-terminal-true-instead-of-removing-lower-priority-directives 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266840/how-to-understand-the-terminal-of-directive